# I've upgraded to Yosemite. Now my Screensaver is goofy!

Tags: macbook-pro

Why does my screensaver continually revert to the default when I've changed it several times, to use My Photos? This is very frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the preference files:

```
/Users/[home folder]/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.screensaver*.plist
```

Open a Finder window, and then open the `Go` menu. When displayed press the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key and appears an option called `Library`. Go to this option and your finder must be on `Library` folder. Then open `Preferences`, then `ByHost` and delete files starting with `com.apple.screensaver` and extension `plist`.

Then restart.

Comment: Guess I'm not computer literate enough to understand where you're directing me. In System Preferences, I don't see Library. I've re-set my preferences, once again, in System Preferences/Screensaver and will Restart now. And hope for the best. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, more details on how to do it in my previous answer.

Comment: copy this in the Finders GO- Go to Folder- /Users/borderline/Library/Preferences/ByHost -then find 3 files com.apple.screensaver